# Websphere MQ : Queue manager cannot connect

Tags: queue, ibm-mq, mq

I have tried the different solutions offered in multiple threads but none of them are solving my issue.
Also I noticed i have no error in my logs so it does not facilitate to find the root cause of my error.
Ok first thing first:

- I am an administrator on my laptop
- I m running Windows 7 64 bit
- I m using MQ 8.0.0.5

When I create a queue manager (btw i open WMQ as an administrator), the queue manager is created but I am getting the message AMQ8157: Security Error
See attached picture
[image]

The queue manager appears under the Queue Managers folder but it will not connect. 
When I click on connect i am getting the error

> An unexpected error (2063) has occurred. (AMQ4999)   An unexpected
>   error (2063) has occurred. (AMQ4999)   Severity: 10 (Warning)
>   Explanation: An unlisted error has occurred in the system while
>   retrieving PCF data.   Response: Try the operation again. If the error
>   persists, examine the problem determination information to see if any
>   details have been recorded.

The .log does not display any error message so i am really stuck.
Below is the only log i m getting when creating the queue manager, nothing when i try to connect.

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2018-07-09 11:10:32.557 !MESSAGE NLS
>   missing message: UI_WIZARD_FILE_SIZE_UNCHANGED2_LABEL in:
>   com.ibm.wmqfte.explorer.elements !SESSION 2018-07-09 11:14:46.319
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.fullversion=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.7 Windows
>   7 amd64-64 Compressed References 20160406_298393 (JIT enabled, AOT
>   enabled) J9VM - R27_Java727_SR3_20160406_0942_B298393 JIT  -
>   tr.r13.java_20160328_114186 GC   -
>   R27_Java727_SR3_20160406_0942_B298393_CMPRSS J9CL - 20160406_298393
>   BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
>   Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2018-07-09 11:14:51.921 !MESSAGE NLS
>   missing message: UI_WIZARD_FILE_SIZE_UNCHANGED2_LABEL in:
>   com.ibm.wmqfte.explorer.elements

Comment: 2063 is a security error. 
Are you using LDAP?  
Are you using an older version of MQ Explorer to try connection? 
Can you confirm the userID that is being used when trying to connect from Explorer? 
Are you able to connect from command line with a sample program such as amqsbcg?

Comment: No i am not using LDAP. I m using my windows user which is an administrator. I open MQ explorer by right clicking on it and run as administrator. I dont know the commend to use from a cmd :-/

Comment: Please, add error logs as mentioned by @tim-mccormick

Answer (score 0):

This definitely seems like an issue related to permissions, you might want to double check on the users and groups for MQ that you have. 
Also, could you check the MQ service if its using the same account which is supposed to be taken. (though its wierd that there aren't any logs for security error)

Comment: Service is started and uses the .\MUSR_MQADMIN . If i try to open Explorer with this user then it fails and does not even open. Only when I run as an administrator then Explorer opens and i can create a queue manager. The issue is that it does not want to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the reason for a security error will be logged by the queue manager in its own error logs (for security reasons you don't want to give the reason the client as they could use this against you). You can find your error logs here:

C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\Mel2\errors

AMQERR01.LOG is the most recent log file.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest mistake people make is trying to do MQ changes under the Administration account (Windows) or root (Unix/Linux).  First, you will make a mess of things and secondly, it does not work as you think it does.

You should ONLY use the Administration or root account for the installation of MQ, after that use your own account.

If you are going to be the "MQAdmin" on your WIndows PC then:

1. Stop using the Administrator account for MQ
2. Use your OWN user account for MQ configuration/administration
3. Add your user account to the "mqm" group
4. Either restart the queue manager(s) or issue the refresh security command
5. Once your UserId is in the "mqm" group, you can configure your queue managers

Note: If you were configuring MQ with Administration account then I would delete EVERYTHING you did under the Administrator account and simply start over doing it the right way.  Otherwise, you will be posting question after question on Stackoverflow asking why "this does not work" and "that does not work".

Comment: This is what I just performend: 1. Added my user account to the mqm group. 2. Stop/start the IBM MQ service. 3. Restart my laptop (so my user changes are taken into account for sure) 4. Open MQ explorer with my account (so not as run as admin). 5. Create a new queue manager. 6. Got the exact same message:  AMQ8157: Security error.

Comment: From your original description, it sounded like you are running the queue manager and MQ Explorer on the same PC.  Therefore, you should be connecting in bindings mode (i.e. local connection) - no network.  If you are connecting in client mode (i.e. IP address & port #) then you need to deal with channel security (i.e. CHLAUTH) rules.  Go read some of Morag's posts: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/chlauth_allow_some_privileged_admins?lang=en  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/websphere_mq_chlauth_the_back_stop_rule?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue.
So,I have the MQMD service , right click on MQMD service, and change the log on to ‘Local System Account’ and and restarted the service and now working fine.